# javascript on crm 2011 polaris process form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

How to run javascript code on a process form (Polaris updated form), other than using an html page hack?

Doesn't Microsoft provide a suitable option/alternative, since an event handler opens with the Classic Form?

Do I have to do my form validations with plugins? I'd rather use javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the HTML Web Resource Hack is the only way to customize the new forms using JavaScript (and is an unsupported customization)

Is necessary to wait the next update from Microsoft that will provide the supported methods.

If your customer still want to use the new forms and you want to customize using plugins, remember to handle also the autosave timeout, to avoid unnecessary updates.

Comment: I thought HTML Web Resources on the new forms was supported!? Have I got that wrong?

Comment: I meant the html web resource hack (put javascript inside html web resource to modify the page). I edited my post to make it clearer, thanks